# display popup into dynamic listview using Jquery mobile

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

after displaying a dynamic list view via WS, i want to click the item to display a popup so
i used the tutorial  http://view.jquerymobile.com/master/demos/popup-dynamic
but it didn't work for dynamic list and work when i try a static list

the JS :

```
$( document ).on( "pagecreate", "#rr",function() {

forge.request.ajax({
//call the WS and fill out the list.
});

 $( ".fav" ).on( "click", function() {
    var target = $( this ),
        // do some things
    $.mobile.activePage.append( popup ); 
    $('[data-role=popup]').popup();
});
```

here a li TAG

```
<li><a href="#" class="fav" ></a></li>
```

Comment: `$( document ).on( "click", ".fav", function() {
    var target = $( this ),
        // do some things
});` as `.fav` is dynamic.

Comment: my problem isn't on there, when i try it with a static list it works good that's mean the problem isn't on method call but he didn't recognize the new element or other thing.

Comment: if `.fav` is static, your code should work, if its dynamic, you need to attach event as I mentioned in my comment.

Comment: ok it works, but when the popup is displayed and hided, the listview has duplicated here items from for example 2 to 4 and 4 items to 8 items ?!!
i edit my post

Comment: you dont need to call `.trigger('pagecreate')` thats why you get duplicate items. append popup and call `$('[data-role=popup]').popup();` and try again.

Comment: thanks it works 
i change the code

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/39497/discussion-between-omar-and-mirlo)